# How to prevent Chrome version 123 from disabling self-hosted extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

We have a self-hosted extension that is deployed to Windows 10 users via Google [Cloud policy.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBM0e.png)

After updating to Chrome version 123, our extension is always disabled by Chrome. It did not happen on previous versions of Chrome.
There is no direct way to reenable the extension. However we noticed that if Chrome opens Extensions page first, then it will keep our extension enabled. It is still not a good solutions, as after closing Chrome our extension will be disabled again regardless of what page was opened. And we need to open Chrome on Extensions page again to enable our extension.

I have enabled Chrome debug logs. When the extensions page is opened first, i see the following:

```
WARNING:force_installed_metrics.cc(452)] All forced extensions seem to be installed
```

On the next start of Chrome I always see this message:

```
WARNING:force_installed_metrics.cc(479)] Failed to install 0 forced extensions.
```

No explanation is given in the logs, as far as I can see.

I also tried changing extension related policies in the registry under

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome
```

I tried all policies listed [here](https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/#Extensions), but to no effect.
And when I tried to use ExtensionSettings, I got this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSoOh.png) in my Chrome policy. Chrome tells me that I can only install extensions from Web Store, since my computer is not managed. But my machine is enrolled in Google Cloud.

I also tried installing the extension via registry by chaning those values, as shown [here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/how-to/distribute/install-extensions#registry):

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Google\Chrome\Extensions
```

but it did not have any effect either.

Is there any way to prevent Chrome from disabling our extension?

Comment: Evidently it's a bug. You can revert Chrome to 122 via policies TargetVersionPrefix + RollbackToTargetVersion. Why is there a `[BLOCKED]` in json? Only the id should be there. I guess Chrome adds it, hence the bug.

Comment: Why is there a `[BLOCKED]` in json? Only the id should be there.

Comment: `[Blocked]` is something that Chrome adds when reading my policy from the registry. 
My original JSON does not contain this text.

Chrome does not add  `[BLOCKED]`  when reading our Cloud policy. So that works as intended.

Comment: wOxxOm, unfortunately, policies TargetVersionPrefix + RollbackToTargetVersion are not apllicable from Windows Registry. I can only edit Windows Registry right now.

Comment: I don't see such limitation in the documentation. You might have to [fake the MDM enrollment](https://hitco.at/blog/apply-edge-policies-for-non-domain-joined-devices/) though.

Comment: I will check your link, thank you. [Policy page](https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/#DeviceTargetVersionPrefix) only lists ChromeOS as compatable, and not Windows. I have tried to set this policy in `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome`, but Chrome did not recognize it.

Comment: You're using the wrong key, see [this reference](https://admx.help/?Category=GoogleUpdate&Policy=Google.Policies.Update::Pol_RollbackToTargetVersionGoogleChromeDev).